# Place Holder not visible react-number-format

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-number-format

##### Current behavior

Place holder is not visible for phone number mask

##### Expected behavior

Place holder to be visible and on focus the input format and mask to be applied while user is entering data

##### CodeSandbox link illustrating the issue

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-jang-0wmx3i?file=/src/App.js

##### Please check the browsers where the issue is seen

- [Version 98.0.4758.109 (Official Build) (x86_64) ] Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have `allowEmptyFormatting ={true}`, which will format the box when empty and thus override the placeholder. [Docs](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format)

You can see the placeholder if you set it to `false`. So confirming its a config output and not related to any browser

```
allowEmptyFormatting ={false}
```